# Moderator suddenly closing bounty question after four days

Tags: discussion, bounties, specific-question, closed-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15450988/1) had a bounty but only after four days a moderator singlehandedly decided it doesn't deserve to be open or to have a bounty.

#### History

The question has never been edited. While it could have been improved, nobody deemed it necessary.

Since it had a bounty, it had to be open for more than two days. Plenty of time for anyone to close it. Nobody did. Then while it had a bounty, it was open for two more days. Plenty of time to close it by a moderator, but no moderator did.

The question, while it could have been written better, even gathered three extended answers. This indicates that people were able to understand the question and answer it. So *it is a valid question*. The OP has upvoted some of these answers and marked one as *the answer*, which indicates that the answers are what the OP expected.

#### Closing

And then after four days and at least three answerers putting effort in their answers, comes along [casperOne♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) who closes the question and removes the bounty. Why?

Non-moderators cannot close a bounty question, and there are good reasons for that. Moderators should take great care before closing such a question and removing the bounty. If one doesn't like the question *downvote it*. If after four days a moderator singlehandedly decides that the bounty question must be closed and none of the answerers deserve a bounty, then there must be a *very good reason*. I can think of none.

**I request the question to be reopened**, as it is a valid algorithmic question. I suspect the bounty will be gone anyways, so those who put more effort in their answers because of the bounty (the whole reason there is a bounty system) won't get rewarded.

Comment: `This indicates that people were able to understand the question and answer it. So it is a valid question.` Being able to understand a question and answer it doesn't automatically make it a valid question (for Stack Overflow). The question shows absolutely no prior effort, which renders it invalid (or, more accurately, not a real question).

Comment: This is a bad question, period, and @casper was perfectly valid in closing it. It is unclear, the amount of clarification required is ridiculous, and it got -3. Nothing to do here.

Comment: @Linuxios Apparently you and Casper cannot see the difference between a _bad question_ (which you downvote) and _not a question_ (which you close). If it was not a question now, then it was not a question four days ago and it had to be closed then already. Then there would be no bounty and no people putting in effort for nothing.

Comment: @Virtlink: who's bounty was it?

Comment: @Linuxios The original OP's. He got it redeemed. Yes, it was a bad question, it could have been a whole lot better. Probably the reason he has to put a bounty on it after two days because he didn't get any quick answers. He's new and learning the system.

Comment: @Virtlink: personally, I consider this a case where the mod shouldn't have used their mod powers, however, I don't think it should be reopened.

Comment: *"If it was not a question now, then it was not a question four days ago and it had to be closed then already."* ..and unfortunately that didn't happen. Not a whole lot of attention for it apparently. (78 views after a bounty and some Meta attention is not a lot). So the only problem here is that it was not closed earlier on,  when it should have been. This has now been corrected.

Comment: Generally, we don't copy the entire contents of a question, especially a currently *undeleted* question into posts on meta.SO.  Please don't do that in the future.

Comment: @Virtlink Don't take this the wrong way, I'm mostly just curious, but why haven't you yet edited the question? Personally I think it's a lost cause, but you clearly don't think so, why wasn't your first reaction to fix anything you can fix in the question? Just the obvious spelling and grammar mistakes would be enough (for me). Is that too much to ask? You clearly found the question interesting enough to answer, why not also spend 5 minutes to improve it (either by editing, or commenting, or both)?

Comment: @Yannis I almost always edit questions I encounter that are like this. I even have the edited question ready on my Notepad. But to be fair when posting this on meta, I didn't edit the post to show what CasperOne saw when he closed the question.

Comment: Cool, that makes sense.

Comment: @casperOne I _will_ copy the question in my metaposts in the future. First and foremost because I intended to edit it and then metapeople would only see my improved version. So I copy the one you moderated here, just to be fair. Second, because not everyone is going to click through to the actual question, and this way I can show the question at hand and the judgment call that was made. Thirdly, I've never seen nor can I find any reference on meta on _not copying questions_, so I suspect you made that up. Ironic that of all people _you_ edit my metaquestion.

Comment: First, no you won't, it *will* simply be edited out and we *will* lock the post if you insist on doing that.  There is a full revision history on the question itself, there is no need to post *anything* from the original question here.  It's *already* fair in that the system is *completely* transparent in the edits (unless your question is about programming on a boat).  Your second point is simply not valid. If people can't be bothered to click through to a link on a site that places performance above all else, then it can be argued that they aren't that vested in the outcome of the meta post.

Comment: @Virtlink Please don't copy the entire original question into your Meta question. We can always look at the various revisions. Copying the entire question is pointless. Just put in a link. Those interested in your Meta question will follow it.

Comment: @Virtlink: if you edit it, you can simply link to the earlier version of the question ([like this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/172670/1)).

Comment: In regards to the third point, I'm digging up the reference now.  This happens a bit on other SE meta sites, but it's been shown that it generally introduces noise, or, because those sites don't have enough 10K users to see deleted posts (which this post is *not*), it's an issue there.  However, that is not the case *here*.

Comment: @casperOne I do recall several instances of users copying entire questions to Meta (though it was Physics or Skeptics I think) to circumvent the deletion of a question (under the disguise of a "discussion"). Perhaps that's the instance you're thinking of?

Comment: @JoachimSauer That is very constructive, thank you. I'll link to the particular revision in the future.

Comment: @bart Yes it was on those sites (and one user in particular, actually), and there was a *comment* that I made to this specific effect on meta.SO, but that's like finding a needle in a haystack.

Answer (score 12):

In the comments you state:

> [Apparently you and Casper [sic] cannot see the difference between a bad question (which you downvote) and not a question (which you close).](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172670/moderator-suddenly-closing-bounty-question-after-four-days#comment512450_172670)

As indicated by many in the comments (on this meta question), this was a bad question, it boils down to "my function needs to do this" and you give a skeleton of a function to be filled in as per your requirements.

We refer to this as a "gimme teh codez" question, and close it as "Not A Real Question".  The reason being that the lack of effort makes satisfies the "incomplete" and "vague" aspects indicated in the close reason.

In your (meta) question, you state:

> This question had a bounty but only after four days a moderator singlehandedly [sic] decided it doesn't deserve to be open or to have a bounty.

This is untrue.  There was a flag on the question.  This indicated that *at least* one other person didn't believe that this question should be open.

Finally, in the same comment you referenced above, you state:

> If it was not a question now, then it was not a question four days ago and it had to be closed then already.

You are right, it was not a question (as per Stack Overflow's standards) four days ago.  However, moderators don't have the ability to monitor every single new question that is posted on Stack Overflow (there are about five-seven *thousand* new questions a day).  Maintaining quality on Stack Overflow is a continuous process, and yes, we don't get to these things as quickly as we'd like to, but we get to them as fast as possible.

In other words, just because it wasn't closed *immediately* doesn't in any way make your question a question that meets the current quality standards of the site (we still close old non-constructive recommendation questions that are *years* old).

Comment: While I don't like so many questions getting closed you bring valid points and moderator decision should be final, except for extreme cases.

Comment: There was a lot of explanation in the beginning, but to close it as NaRQ is a little extreme. The question is right there, "How do I divide an array into separate arrays in C#?" that's the crux of his problem. Only one person said they didn't understand it.. others were looking for clarification in the comments.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes, and if the moderator decision *is* disputed then coming to Meta is the perfect solution. (However it should not really be done in such a confrontational manner as this question!).

Comment: Of course the question was a bad question, I never contested that. But bad questions _get downvoted_, not closed. How can there be three answers to something that is - according to you - _not a question_ at all? (BTW, thanks for sic-cing my spelling mistakes. IamDutchandtendtowriteeverytingtogether)

Comment: @0A0D Not extreme at all.  It's incomplete and vague.  It doesn't specify the *specific* problem that the OP is having.  Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.  It's also not a legitimate "question" in the literal sense of the word in that it doesn't *ask* anything, it's essentially a statement that says "do this for me.".  I'm sorry, but we will *not*.

Comment: @casperOne: I just looked at it again and apparently George Stocker made it into a useful question a few minutes ago. I take back what I said, I didn't see that.

Comment: @Virtlink maybe better description instead of "Not a Real Question" would be "Question that does not match Stack Overflow standards", thus does not deserve to be answered.

Comment: @Virtlink See [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172670/moderator-suddenly-closing-bounty-question-after-four-days/172679#comment512508_172679) as well as the answer as to why "gimme teh codez" questions are really not even "questions", let alone a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @0A0D It's formatted, and has a better description of what is desired, but it's still a statement saying "do this for me."

Comment: @casperOne: That's really a gray area because when you ask a question, you are asking someone to solve a problem for you.

Comment: @casperOne: I also take issue with your statement, "As indicated by many in the comments". There was one comment.

Comment: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172670/moderator-suddenly-closing-bounty-question-after-four-days/172679#comment512444_172670), [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172670/moderator-suddenly-closing-bounty-question-after-four-days/172679#comment512446_172670), [3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172670/moderator-suddenly-closing-bounty-question-after-four-days/172679#comment512457_172670), [4](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172670/moderator-suddenly-closing-bounty-question-after-four-days/172679#comment512464_172670) is that not enough for you?

Comment: @0A0D Note, while not all agree that a moderator should have closed it, they all agree it *should be closed*.

Comment: @casperOne: I am talking about the question itself, not on Meta. The issue discussed on Meta was after-the-fact.

Comment: @0A0D I've clarified with "(on this meta question)", good enough?

Comment: @casperOne: Look, no need to be passive aggressive about it. We just don't agree with you.

Comment: @0A0D It's not passive aggressive, I'm asking because you're not being clear with what you take issue with.  In trying to address what I *thought* was your issue (and asking for your approval) you've not actually helped to clarify what you've taken issue with.

Comment: " I've clarified with "(on this meta question)", good enough? " and "1, 2, 3, 4 is that not enough for you?". Listen how that sounds. That's passive aggressive language. Anyways, those of us against it take issue with the NaRQ close reason and / or the "gimme the codez" reason.

Comment: @0A0D "I also take issue with your statement, "As indicated by many in the comments". There was one comment." **You're not being clear here**

Comment: @casperOne: The only one not being clear was you, since you revised your question.

Comment: @casperOne i can understand why you closed it, but people put effort in their answers for bounty, and yes its "gimme the codez" but i was giving bounty for it and this is the only question in which i didn't include what i tried, because everything i tried was not dynamic and did not function the way i needed, and if included it people would have a harder time understanding the question, so i needed their thoughts without my thoughts involved, you may say it has no use in the real world but it is meant for a puzzle game, please reopen it so i can give the bounty

Comment: @user1590636 Sorry, but if a user answers a question that they know to be bad in the hopes of getting a bounty, then they need to understand the risk/reward proposition and the fact that the bounty may be revoked and the question closed.  A bounty does not protect a bad question from being closed.

Comment: @user1590636 Also, I'm *very* inclined to delete the entire thing because of the *four* "gay downvoters" comments.  However, that would be wrong, because that's not a reflection of the question and not the user.  However, that is *not* appropriate for Stack Overflow.  Do not make comments of that nature again, or you *will* be suspended.  Please see the ["be nice" section of the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#benice).  It's not just there for show, it's something we take very seriously around here.